# Converting a C# Method to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using SQL Server to manage my data for a website. I just decided to add two new columns to the database and I want to populate these two columns for every row in the table. To populate each of the columns I am using information from another table. I have created a method that does it for me in C# but it takes a really long time. Its about 35,000 rows. Here is what my C# method does but I was wondering if it would be better to make this a stored procedure and if it is better how could i go about doing it?

```
    public void UpdateAssignedCountAndLastReponseDate()
    {
        //Loop through each task in the database 
        foreach (var task in IssueDb.AP_Tasks.ToList())
        {
            // Check to see if there is both not a null and a last response date
            if (task.AssignedCount != null && task.LastReponseDate != null) continue;
            //Check the task history for records
            var taskhistory = from x in IssueDb.AP_TaskHistory
                              where x.TaskID == task.TaskID && x.AssignDate != null
                              select x;
            //get last response date
            var maxAssignDate = (from th in IssueDb.AP_TaskHistory where task.TaskID == th.TaskID orderby th.AssignDate descending select th.AssignDate).FirstOrDefault();
            IssueDb.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
            task.LastReponseDate = maxAssignDate;
            //get count
            task.AssignedCount = taskhistory.Count();
            if (task.LastReponseDate == null)
                task.LastReponseDate = task.TaskDate;
            if (task.AssignedCount == null)
                task.AssignedCount = 0;
            //save these numbers to task columns in the DB
            IssueDb.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I am currently doing this in the EF5 in ASP. NET Application MVC

Here is what I have so far:

```
   UPDATE [dbo].[AP_Tasks]
   SET [AssignedCount] =
   (
        CASE [AssignedCount] IS NULL THEN (SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[AP_TaskHistory] INNER JOIN [AP_TaskHistory] WHERE [AP_TaskHistory].[TaskID] == [AP_Tasks].[TaskID] AND [AP_TaskHistory].[AssignDate] IS NOT NULL)

   );
   SET [LastReponseDate] =
   (
        CASE [AP_Tasks].[LastReponseDate] IS NULL
        THEN (SELECT FIRST(AssignDate) FROM [dbo].[AP_TaskHistory] INNER JOIN [AP_TaskHistory] WHERE [AP_TaskHistory].[TaskID] == [AP_Tasks].[TaskID] AND [AP_TaskHistory].[AssignDate] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [AP_TaskHistory].[AssignDate] DESC)
   );
```

Here are my errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 11
'FIRST' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your update statement and cleaned it up:

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[AP_Tasks]
SET     [AssignedCount] = ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                            FROM    [dbo].[AP_TaskHistory]
                            WHERE  [AP_TaskHistory].[TaskID] = [AP_Tasks].[TaskID] AND  [AP_TaskHistory].[AssignDate] IS NOT NULL
                          ) ,
        [LastReponseDate] = ( SELECT    MAX(AssignDate)
                              FROM      [dbo].[AP_TaskHistory]
                              WHERE  [AP_TaskHistory].[TaskID] = [AP_Tasks].[TaskID] AND  [AP_TaskHistory].[AssignDate] IS NOT NULL
                            )
```

1. fixed syntax
2. removed CASE statement, if these are new columns you don't have to worry about existing data

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server you can do an update statement that joins other tables.  Here is an example

```
UPDATE u
SET u.FirstName = t2.SomeColumn
FROM Users u
     INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON (u.UserID = t2.UserID)
```

And since you're using EF you can put this into your migration script.

This approach would be much, much faster!

Comment: Can you help me with my stored procedure?

Answer (score -1):

For sure it will be faster with a stored procedure.

The code of your stored procedure will look very similar to your C# codes, you can use while, if/else statement, ...

Comment: Why will it be faster? I don't think that blanket statement will be true here....

Comment: first because there isn't a connection and data's transmission between your application and your BDD and also because SQL server is optimize for manipulate a lot of data.

Comment: All good points - but those apply just the same if you send a properly parametrized SQL query to SQL Server - it will have the exact same benefits, the exact same execution sequence .... It's a *myth* that using a stored procedure will be *faster* ....

Comment: He has to populate 35,000 rows so that mean a lot of data's transmission, with a stored procedure you don't need to do this transmission so you win this transmission time

Comment: My point exactly - with a properly parametrized query, you also **DO NOT** need to transfer any data to your C# application! Everything happens on the server - just like with a stored procedure!

Comment: Oh yes you're right, but you have more functionality with stored procedure than query. After it depend what do you need to do but you're right.